# Making sense of nested lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates, generic-lambda

My question pertains to the following nested lambda expression, provided as an example under [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

```
// generic lambda, operator() is a template with one parameter
auto vglambda = [](auto printer) {
    return [=](auto&&... ts) // generic lambda, ts is a parameter pack
    { 
        printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
        return [=] { printer(ts...); }; // nullary lambda (takes no parameters)
    };
};
auto p = vglambda([](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; });
auto q = p(1, 'a', 3.14); // outputs 1a3.14
q();                      // outputs 1a3.14
```

The following is the way I interpret the above expression:

In the expression

```
auto p = vglambda([](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; });
```

the closure object `vglambda` is initialized with the closure object `printer` whose type corresponds to the lambda expression

```
[](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; }
```

Inside `printer`, the nested (anonymous) lambda expression

```
return [=](auto&&... ts){}
```

captures `printer` by copy and its parameter pack as `rvalue` reference.

Inside the body of the (anonymous) lambda expression, the expression

```
printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
```

forwards the parameter pack to `printer` [in what essentially appears to be an invocation of `printer` using `operator ()`]

In the final expression inside the body of the (anonymous) lambda expression, the (anonymous) nullary lambda expression appears to capture the `printer` closure object from the enclosing scope by copy, along with the parameter pack, and invokes the `printer` closure object with its forwarded parameter pack.

```
return [=] { printer(ts...); };
```

Now, it is very evident that I am not getting something right here. Essentially, why are two distinct lines of invoking the `printer` closure object provided within the body of the (anonymous) lambda expression, one without the (anonymous) nullary lambda expression, and one within?

Can any of the experts throw more light?

Comment: Your code uses a generic lambda, introduced from C++14; so I've changed your C++11 tag in C++14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the expression
>
> ```
> auto p = vglambda([](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; });
> ```
>
> the closure object `vglambda` is initialized with the closure object printer whose type corresponds to the lambda expression
>
> ```
> [](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; }
> ```

It seems to me more correct say that `vglamba` is **invoked** with the lambda that uses `std::cout`. `vglambda` is **initialized** with a generic lambda function that receive a generic (`auto`) value (`printer`).

> Inside `printer`, the nested (anonymous) lambda expression
>
> ```
> return [=](auto&&... ts){}
> ```
>
> captures printer by copy and its parameter pack as rvalue reference.

Not inside `printer` (that is only the argument of the lambda) but inside the lambda that is saved in the `vglambda` variable.

Yes, the anonymous nested generic and variadic function captures `printer` by value but isn't precise that the `... ts` are captured (are arguments) and by rvalue reference.

The nested lambda is almost equivalent to a template function (well... to a struct with a template `operator()` inside it... but to make it simpler...)

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto func (Ts && ... ts)
 { /*...*/ }
```

In this case the `&&` aren't rvalue references but **forwarding** **references** (see [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) for more information), as you can see from the inside use of `std::forward`.

This is an important point, but see next.

> Inside the body of the (anonymous) lambda expression, the expression
>
> ```
> printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
> ```
>
> forwards the parameter pack to `printer` [in what essentially appears to be an invocation of printer using `operator ()`]

This seems to me correct.

> In the final expression inside the body of the (anonymous) lambda expression, the (anonymous) nullary lambda expression appears to capture the `printer` closure object from the enclosing scope by copy, along with the parameter pack, and invokes the `printer` closure object with its forwarded parameter pack.
>
> ```
> return [=] { printer(ts...); };
> ```

This seems to me correct but you should see a problem here (together with the preceding `printer()` invocation.

> why are two distinct lines of invoking the printer closure object provided within the body of the (anonymous) lambda expression, one without the (anonymous) nullary lambda expression, and one within?

See how `p` is used

```
auto p = vglambda([](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; });
auto q = p(1, 'a', 3.14);

q();
```

How is initialized `p`?

`p` is initialized with the generic and variadic lambda defined inside the lambda that initialize `vglambda`. So when is called

```
auto q = p(1, 'a', 3.14);
```

you have that the generic variadic lambda is called with the variadic pack `ts...` that is expanded as `1`, `'a'` and `3.14`.

So, calling `p(1, 'a', 3.14)`, you have that is invoked (ignoring the forwarding part)

```
printer(1, 'a', 3.14);
```

(where `printer()` is the lambda that `std::cout` `a`, `b` and `c`) **and** that is returned `[=] { printer(1, 'a', 3.14); }`.

So `q` is initialized with `[=] { printer(1, 'a', 3.14); }` and, calling

```
q();
```

`printer(1, 'a', 3.14)` is called again.

So the idea of the generic and variadic lambda is to call `print()`, with the variadic argument received, a first time **and** return another lambda that `print()` again when invoked.

So from `p(1, 'a', 3.14)` you activate the first `print()` (the one with `std::forward`) and every time you call the returned value (`q`, in your example) you activate the second `print()` (the one without `std::forward`).

But there is a big defect in your code. A defect that doesn't give problems invoking `p()` with primitive types as `int`, `char` and `double`. But a defect that is dangerous using complex objects that support move semantic.

The problem is that, using `std::forward`, you could activate move semantics.

So in this code

```
return [=](auto&&... ts) // generic lambda, ts is a parameter pack
{ 
    printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
    return [=] { printer(ts...); }; // <- DANGER: unsafe use of `ts...`
};
```

the first `printer()` call is safe and correct (using `std::forward`) but the second call to `printer()` is dangerous because we don't know if the `ts...` are still usable.

Using `ts...` **two** times, I suggest to rewrite the lambda as follows

```
return [=](auto const & ... ts)
{ 
    printer(ts...);
    return [=] { printer(ts...); };
};
```